# How to create an object from a prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am new to JavaScript and currently reading the book "JavaScript: The Good Parts". I am trying to understand the following:

```
function create(proto) {
    var F = function() { };
    F.prototype = proto;
    return new F();
}
function create2(proto) {
    var o = { };
    o.prototype = proto;
    return o;
}
var o = { }, c1 = create(o), c2 = create2(o);
o.status = 'OK';
document.writeln(c1.status);
document.writeln(c2.status);
```

`create(proto)` is how this is done in the book.
`create2(proto)` is how I thought it should work.
Obviously, the example from the book is working while mine is not, so the output is:

```
OK
undefined
```

Now my question is: Why does `create2(proto)` not work like `create(proto)`?

Comment: there is because var o = { }; is an object literal and not a function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572) - `F` is a function while `o` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `create`, you are creating a new object with the help of a constructor function (`new F()`). So, the prototype chain is established, between `proto` object and the object constructed with the constructor function.

In `create2`, you are creating an Object and creating a property on it with the name `prototype`. In this case, the prototype chain is not established.

That is why the object created by `create2`, couldn't go up the prototype chain to find `status`.

**Note:** In the second case, you can still do

```
document.writeln(c2.prototype.status);
```

Answer (score 1):

In create2 method if you need the standard prototype in not the standard "prototype". If you want this to work you need to use `Object.setPrototypeOf(o, proto)`
The new created property "prototype" will be the satellite object that will have symbolic link to the 
parent object.

```
function create(proto) {
 var F = function() { };
 F.prototype = proto;
 return new F(); 
} 

function create2(proto) {
var o = { };
Object.setPrototypeOf(o, proto);
return o;
}
var o = { }, c1 = create(o), c2 = create2(o);
o.status = 'OK';
console.log(c1.status);
console.log(c2.status);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. FYI: This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari and also my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate) doesn't recognize `Object.setPrototypeOf(o, proto)`.